# В Linux, Кешируются ли файлы в tmpfs в ОЗУ (можно ли оптимизировать эту логичность-не?

Tags: linux, tmpfs

В Linux,  Кешируются ли файлы в tmpfs в ОЗУ (можно ли оптимизировать эту логичность-не?

Comment: tmpfs сам по себе и есть кеш в ОЗУ без персистентного хранения. Непонятно, что вы там собрались оптимизировать. tmpfs / rawmfs не несут в себе много пользы.

Answer (score 1):

> В Linux, Кешируются ли файлы в tmpfs в ОЗУ

И да и нет, дело в том что вся `tmpfs` собственно и построена вокруг подсистемы кеширования файлов. Т.е. всё содержимое файлов в ней всегда хранится в виде кешированных страниц в ОЗУ; а, например, при нехватке памяти страницы кеша целиком  в таком состоянии будут сброшены в область подкачки.

> можно ли оптимизировать эту логичность-не?

Не особо понятно, что вообще тут можно хотеть оптимизировать...

Comment: Я подозреваю, что вопрос ТС исходил из предположения, что файлы в /tmp размещаются в RAM в тех же структурах, что и обычно на HDD, а при обращении к ним, данные кэшируются так же, как данные остальных файлов. Вот про эту "нелогичность" (дважды занимаемый RAM) он и спрашивал. Надеюсь, ваш ответ развеял его опасения.